# Programming in sp2013

Tags: development, css, html, html-editor

What is the best way to edit the sp 2013 html/css and js?
Currently i am using a text editor, and then uploading the newly edited code to the sp site. 
Is there not a better and more effective way to access and edit the code in sp 2013?

Comment: you could work directly with the uploaded file? or how are you uploading your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use SharePoint Designer to update files. Open your uploaded files in SharePoint Designer, Update it and save. No need to manually upload it again.

Comment: is there not a text editor within sharepoint designer?

Comment: @furatmahmoud what are you using right now?

Comment: I am using brackets as a text editor, and sp 2013.. I think it is difficult to do it in this way, because I can not remember how to edit it.. I have edited the code with succes many times before, but i cannot remember how to find the file, and then uploading it and so on.. sometimes I miss basic web development lol.. If you can tell me a better way, it would be so awesome.. if not I really appreciate your help..!

Comment: I like sp and i like css etc.. but my difficulty is to combine the two elements.. maybe it is just some startup issues :)

Comment: Use SharePoint designer

Comment: One last question. I promise not to torture you anymore after this :) When I go into sharepoint designer, where should I go then?

Comment: @furatmahmoud where are your css file uploaded??

Comment: I know it is inside SP designer. I cannot remember where, but I will find out. thank you for the hint and your help Rajesh :D

Comment: it is in site assets folder?